# Spring Boot: Throwing exception in WebClient does not caught on my exception controller handler

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, microservices, webclient

I'm creating a component class that overrides a reactive method that calls another microservice "uaa" that validates a token, but when I verify that the token is invalid I throw an exception, but that exception does not catch in my exception controller handler
here is my component class

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthFilter implements GlobalFilter {

    private final JwtTokenProviderService jwtTokenProviderService;
    private final TokenStatusDaoService tokenStatusDaoService;
    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        log.info("something in the way");
        List<String> headers = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(headers)) {
            log.trace("Request came without token");
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        } else {
            String authToken = headers.get(0);
            log.trace("Request holds a token");
            log.debug("Check if token has expired ...");
            if(jwtTokenProviderService.isTokenExpired(authToken)) {
                log.debug("Token has expired will throw an error");
                throw new AuthorizationForbiddenException(AuthorizationForbiddenExceptionTitleEnum.TOKEN_HAS_EXPIRED, "Token has expired");

            }else {
                log.debug("Check if token is valid and already saved");
                String userId = jwtTokenProviderService.getClaimsFromToken(authToken).get(SecurityUtils.IDENTIFIER_KEY).toString();
                if(!tokenStatusDaoService.exists(TokenStatusSpecification.withToken(authToken).and(TokenStatusSpecification.withUserId(Long.parseLong(userId))))) {
                    return webClient.get()
                            .uri("http://uaa", uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                                    .path("/validate-token")
                                    .queryParam("token", authToken).build()).retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(TokenValidationGetResource.class)
                            .map(tokenValidationGetResource -> {
                                if (!tokenValidationGetResource.isValid()) {
                                    log.debug("token is not valid");
                                    throw new AuthorizationForbiddenException(AuthorizationForbiddenExceptionTitleEnum.TOKEN_NOT_VALID, "Token is not valid");
                                } else {
                                    log.debug("token is valid");
                                    TokenStatusEntity tokenStatusEntity;
                                    try {
                                        tokenStatusEntity = tokenStatusDaoService.findOne(TokenStatusSpecification.withUserId(Long.parseLong(userId)));
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        log.debug("No token defined for user: {}. Will save a new one ...", userId);
                                        tokenStatusEntity = new TokenStatusEntity();
                                    }
                                    tokenStatusEntity.setToken(authToken);
                                    tokenStatusEntity.setUserId(Long.parseLong(userId));
                                    tokenStatusEntity.setStatus(TokenStatusEnum.VALID);
                                    tokenStatusDaoService.save(tokenStatusEntity);
                                    log.debug("Token status entity: {}", tokenStatusEntity);
                                    return exchange;
                                }
                            }).flatMap(chain::filter);
                } else {
                    log.debug("Token exists in DB");
                    return chain.filter(exchange);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my exception controller handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerImpl implements ExceptionController {

    @Override
    @ExceptionHandler({
            AuthorizationForbiddenException.class
    })
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetailResource> handleGenericExceptions(
            AbstractBaseException e, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ErrorDetailResource errorDetailResource = new ErrorDetailResource();
        errorDetailResource.setTimestamp(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
        errorDetailResource.setTitle(e.getTitle().toString());
        errorDetailResource.setCode(e.getTitle().getCode());
        errorDetailResource.setDeveloperMessage(e.getClass().getName());
        errorDetailResource.setStatus(e.getStatus().value());
        errorDetailResource.setDetail(e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetailResource, e.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception handlers work for requests handled by the srevlet. This is a filter which is excecuted before that.

Comment: is there any better way to handle this case?

Comment: I was confused, this is a reactive filter not a servlet filter. The exception handlers are for the servlet API not the reactive API that has other means of handling errors globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Those exceptions are thrown on a mono method in a reactive manner, so they can not be caught by controller advice, instead of doing that create a class which will extends the abstract class AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
public class GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    public GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler(GlobalErrorAttributes globalErrorAttributes,
            ApplicationContext applicationContext,
            ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer) {
        super(globalErrorAttributes, new WebProperties.Resources(), applicationContext);
        super.setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters());
        super.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(), this::renderErrorResponse);
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(ServerRequest request) {

        final Map<String, Object> errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes(request, ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());
        Throwable error = null;
        // here is your abstract base exception
        AbstractBaseException baseException = null;
        try {
            baseException = (AbstractBaseException) getError(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = getError(request);
        }

        HttpStatus statusCode = baseException != null ? baseException.getStatus() : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        return ServerResponse.status(statusCode)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(errorPropertiesMap));
    }
}
```

And of course do not forget to add DefaultErrorAttributes

```
@Component
public class GlobalErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(ServerRequest request, ErrorAttributeOptions options) {
        Throwable error = null;
        // here is your abstract base exception
        // cast the error to your exception class
        AbstractBaseException baseException = null;
        try {
            baseException = (AbstractBaseException) getError(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = getError(request);
        }

        Map<String, Object> errorResources = new HashMap<>();

        // Define the attribute that you want to return in response body
        errorResources.put("attribute1", Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
        errorResources.put("attribute2", baseException != null ? baseException.getStatus() : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

        return errorResources;
    }
}
```